# BicGStab yields unexpected breakdown flag

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I need to solve a cascade of sparse linear systems `Ax=b`. The solution `x` of the first systems is an input to the second system, which is an input to the third and so on. Because of numerical errors compounding and for other reasons, I have to use `scipy.sparse.linalg.bicgstab` as my linear solver. However, for a system that is not even ill-conditioned and definitely has an inverse, the solver gives me a flag for: "illegal input or breakdown".

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import bicgstab, inv
from scipy import sparse

A = np.array(
    [[ -1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,  -1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0., -10.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0., -10.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   3.,   0.,  -3.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   3.,   0.,  -3.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   7.,   3.,   0., -10.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   7.,   0.,   0.,   3.,   0., -10.]]
)
A = -sparse.csc_matrix(A)
b = np.array([ 1.,  0., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
x, flag = bicgstab(A=A, b=b, maxiter=40, tol=1e-6)
x, flag
```

```
>>> (array([1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.00118012,
        0.        , 0.3004875 , 0.70009946]), -10)
```

Just to prove the point

```
inv(A).dot(b)
```

```
>>> array([1. , 0. , 1. , 0. , 1. , 0. , 0.3, 0.7])
```

The output above is exactly what I expect. Does anyone know why bicgstab is not giving me the desired output? I could not find documentation on illegal input or breakdown for bicgstab, and therefore I am my question on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-10` error code does not necessarily mean that you have a wrong input; in your case, it is most likely that the breakdown occurred during the iterative solve.

By slightly changing your RHS:

```
b = np.array([ 1.,  0., 0.,  0.,  10.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

the `scipy.bicgstab` has no troubles converging even without a preconditioner:

```
x, flag = bicgstab(A=A, b=b, maxiter=40, tol=1e-6)
print (x, flag)
```

> ```
> (array([1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 3.33333333,
>    0.        , 1.        , 0.        ]), 0)
> ```

The fact that the matrix has an inverse and a decent condition number

```
print(np.linalg.cond(A))
```

> ```
> 14.616397823169317
> ```

does not guarantee that it is easy to obtain a solution for **a particular RHS**, especially using an iterative solver or a **particular iterative solver**. It seems to me (without an elaborate analysis of the matrix spectrum and its kernel space), that your RHS lies exactly in such a "bad region".

If you are simply interested in a solution, I would suggest switching to GMRES:

```
x, flag = gmres(A=A, b=b, maxiter=40, tol=1e-6)
```

> (array([1.  , 0.  , 0.1 , 0.  , 0.1 , 0.  , 0.03, 0.07]), 0)

If you are interested in investigating why BiCGStab failed, while GMRES succeded in the solution of this system, I would invite your narrowed down question to [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi, how can I find out how to use `tol` and `atol` to achieve the kind of results I'd want?

Comment: @amzon-ex `tol` gives an error in the `x` wrt right-hand side `b` that will be achieved within the iterative process, so, it will be your choice on how accurate you need the result to be in the relative (`tol`) or absolute (`atol`) sense. Not sure if I get your question right.

Comment: That makes some sense. To be more precise, my question is: the doc states that the error in an iterative step (or the *residual*) is given as `norm(residual) <= max(tol*norm(b), atol)`. Now this means that I should have to choose both `tol` and `atol` because if I choose one to be low and leave the other untouched, the solver sides with the larger tolerance (since there's a `max` function). But I don't understand if there's a prescription to specify `tol` and `atol` depending on my problem. In my case, for instance, I know what `norm(b)` is.